# How to fix time delay after the modal confirmation ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an AJAX request after a modal confirmation. Without a modal confirmation the AJAX is fast, but after I show a modal and click the confirm button the AJAX is slow.

I've tried to convert `$.ajax` to `$.post` which is silly. Then I tried to make a function for AJAX and called it and that doesn't work also. I'm expecting a faster or more efficient way of doing this.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#somebutton", function() {
  var modal = $("#modal");
  modal.modal("show");
});

$(document).on("click", "#modalconfirm_button", function() {
  var modal = $("#modal");
  modal.modal("hide");
  var somedata = $(this).data('somedata');

  $.post('/myurl', {
    "somedata": somedata,
  }, function(data) {
    if (data) {
      // some code
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: _Slow_  ... it can also be due to delay response from SQL database engine. You should debug, cause JavaScript executes with same phase. Its the response where it must be causing the delay.

Comment: Found the problem the data attributes i'm sending are not in my modal button on line 7. @ARr0w like you said my python doesn't have validation for null values.

Comment: great. I'll write an answer then, if it helped you do accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript Executes with same pace. It must be causing issue on the Server Side, try checking network tab of Inspection window on browser to find the real cause and issue ajax is generating. See below Image to get the idea of Inspection Window of Chrome.

[image: as Shown in this Picture]